# Array storage in memory

Tags: c++, memory

I am reading a stream of chars and I need them straight as uint64_t values. I used the following approach. But it seems that the array is stored in backward order. However the memory locations are in order when I output their addresses. Sorry if this is a too dumb question. I am struggling to figure out my basic memory knowledge.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned char ar[8] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    uint64_t num = *((uint64_t*)ar);
    std::cout << num << std::endl;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        std::printf("%lu %x\n", i, &ar[i]);
    }
}
```

Following is the output

```
1
0 ffffcc08
1 ffffcc09
2 ffffcc0a
3 ffffcc0b
4 ffffcc0c
5 ffffcc0d
6 ffffcc0e
7 ffffcc0f
```

I expected the result of `num` to be 2^56.

Comment: This is called *endianess*. You should reverse the order of the bytes. Note that a different computer might have different endianess, and you won't need to reverse the bytes. There's nothing in C++ that says the bytes have to be in one order or another.

Comment: I think you get my intentions. What is the best portable approach? @john

Comment: There's no strictly portable approach I know of. You could write a test for one integer, and see which way round things are and then use that for all subsequent conversions.

Comment: Is there any branch-less approach, fellow stackoverflowers? I need this in a performance critical code segment. For now, I would use your approach. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Do you know which target you are compiling for? Conditional compilation would be the most efficient and semi portable approach.

Comment: Depending on your compiler, you may be able to [write really dumb code and still get a good result](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dVyK-C). No such luck for MSVC though.

Comment: "What is the best portable approach?" There is no need to write such a code! Writing something somewhere to memory and tell the compiler it is something totally different is simply a NoGo! If you want to have a integer value and want to set values with specific bit offsets, simply use shift operator. What you wrote is a bad hack and should be avoided, not only because it is non portable.

Comment: @Klaus I am not considering about neat coding practices at this point. I am on for hacking if it is available.

Comment: There is so much to learn about good coding practice for fast, maintainable, easy to extend and most of all reusable code, that I believe that any activity on such kind of "hacking" is only wasting time. Writing non portable, dangerous and obvious code is nothing which helps anyone, especially not yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the endian, your system is little endian and you read the `uint64_t` like you are in a big endian system.
there is one compile time solution without branching in c++20:

you can use [`std::endian`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) to find the `endian` at compile time and use `if constexpr` to decide how your functions work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void print()
{
    constexpr bool is_little_endian = (std::endian::native == std::endian::little); 
    if constexpr (is_little_endian) {
        unsigned char ar[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
        T num = *((T*)ar);
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
    } else {
        unsigned char ar[8] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        T num = *((T*)ar);
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    print<uint64_t>();
}
```

Output

> 72057594037927936

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/IBA-np)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go with this solution.